# add column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to add a column named **Id** in a data frame that contains the name of author id's like Author-Id-001, Author-Id-002... and so on till 150.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.
[something like this(instead of Test-Document-00* I need Author-Id-00*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaqG8.png)

Comment: Can you add data sample?

Comment: please check I added the photo

Comment: [Please don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: It was not a code. it was just a snap of CSV file.

Comment: Yes, but also is better data add to question like text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need:

```
df['Id'] = ['Author-Id-{:03d}'.format(x) for x in range(1, 151)]
```